# On the Laurent series of $\frac{\sin z}{z-1}$ at $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Perhaps it is an easy question, but what would be the Laurent series expansion of the function $\frac{\sin z}{z-1}$ in powers of $z-1$, valid in the domain $0<|z-1|<\infty$?

Isn't that 
$$\frac{\sin z}{z-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(z-1)^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}\ ?
$$

Comment: You have expanded $\sin(z-1)$, not $\sin z$.

Comment: When you're massaging these to fit different center points for the expansions, you're effectively adding and subtracting clever forms of 0. $z-1$ is already in the right form, so you just have to work with the numerator. $\sin(z) = \sin(z-1+1) = \sin(z-1)\cos(1) + \cos(z-1) \sin(1)$ which you can now expand around 1 easily (just plug directly into the Taylor series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not correct. The Laurent series of $\sin(z)$ around $z=1$ is given by $$\sin(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(k)}(1)}{k!}(z-1)^k,$$

where $$f^{(k)}(1)=\begin{cases}\sin(1)&k\in 4\mathbb N\\ \cos(1)&k\in 4\mathbb N+1\\ -\sin(1)&k\in 4\mathbb N+2\\ -\cos(1)&k\in 4\mathbb N+3.\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Surb's answer, you can write
$$\frac{\sin(z)}{z-1}=\sum_{n=-1}^\infty \frac{\cos \left(1+n\frac{\pi }{2}\right)}{(n+1)!}(z-1)^n$$